# How to avoid the virtual keyword

Tags: c++, inheritance

How can  i reach derived class's member function without virtual key.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Employee{
public:
     void what(){
        cout<<"Employee"<<endl;
    }
};
class Secretary:public Employee{
    public:
    void what(){
        cout<<"Secretary"<<endl;
    }
};
class Manager:public Employee{
    public:
    void what(){
        cout<<"Manager"<<endl;
    }
};
class Director:public Manager{
    public:
    void what(){
        cout<<"Director"<<endl;
    }
};
void f(Employee*);
int main(){
    Employee a;
    Manager b;
    Director c;
    Secretary d;
    f(&a);
    f(&b);
    f(&c);
    f(&d);
    return 1;
}
void f(Employee *a){
    a->what();
}
```

It always prints "Employee" . I want to print class's name of each object.
and a.what() prints it's class name correctly. But i have to use pointer and f(Employee *) function on this assignment .

Comment: you can put an identifier in each type as to what type it is.. employee = 1, manager = 2, director = 3 and switch on that.  There is also something called "tagged dispatch" https://crazycpp.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/tutorial-on-tag-dispatching/

Comment: You cannot. Virtual functions are **the only** reason derived classes exist. Does your assignment say you should not use virtual functions? If so, drop out.

Comment: You could use static dispatch with templates.  Is that allowed?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I thought about that but how can that be done with multiple levels of inheritence. e.g. Director derives from Manager.

Comment: @PaulRooney Yes.  I just tried to do it and found out it is much harder than I was imagining...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? If it's a requirement of the assignment, your instructors needs to study up on C++ themselves. I will however take that back if they intend for you to write templated code, and you simply misrepresented your mission statement to us.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, Here is a completely contrived method that doesn't use `virtual` inspired by the comment by @Stephen - it just stores the text in the base class so that when the function f slices the class the data is still there.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Employee{
public:
    std::string name;
    Employee(std::string name = "Employee"):name(name){}
    void what(){
        cout<<name<<endl;
    }
};
class Secretary:public Employee{
    public:
    Secretary(std::string name = "Secretary"):Employee(name){}
};
class Manager:public Employee{
    public:
    Manager(std::string name = "Manager"):Employee(name){}
};
class Director:public Manager{
    public:
    Director(std::string name = "Director"):Manager(name){}
};
void f(Employee*);
int main(){
    Employee a;
    Manager b;
    Director c;
    Secretary d;
    f(&a);
    f(&b);
    f(&c);
    f(&d);
    return 1;
}
void f(Employee *a){
    a->what();
}
```

Comment: `f` does not slice

Comment: This is what I had in mind. I don't know why he wouldn't want virtual

Answer (score 2):

You would have to overload the void f() function to handle the Manager datatype.

```
void f(Manager *a){
    a->what();
}
```

But it would only be accurate for Manager datatypes, and none of the classes derived from manager.

If you wanted to create one function to rule them all for the employee class, and use base-class pointers to access derived members, you'd need to use the virtual keyword. It's just a requirement of C++. (I'm sure there's other ways, because C++ is extremely flexible, but they are very complicated and take time and extra code.)

You would, however, only be required to type 'virtual' in the base class, though that is considered bad practice. Like so:

```
class Employee{
public:
    virtual void what(){
        cout<<"Employee"<<endl;
    }
};

class Secretary:public Employee{
public:
    void what(){ /*Still inherits 'virtual' without typing it.*/
        cout<<"Secretary"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is:

```
void f(Employee*a) { a->what(); }
void f(Secretary*a) { a->what(); }
void f(Manager*a) { a->what(); }
void f(Director*a) { a->what(); }
```

You could use a template instead of writing out the four copies:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T *a) { a->what(); }
```